# Trying to create an Insert function

Tags: function, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to create a function in Postgres 8.4 using pgAdmin and I have the following code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spcwriteperson(IN fname varchar(20))
  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
    INSERT INTO person ("firstName") VALUES(fname);
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

when I try to run this, it complains that fname at VALUES(fname) is not a column.  I'm coming from writing sprocs and functions in MySQL and Sql Server.  Any help on why this doesn't work, or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't like using numbered parameters, you can make use of [PL/PGSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/plpgsql.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spcwriteperson(fname varchar(20)) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO person (firstName) VALUES (fname);
END
$$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

PL/PGSQL will also give you a language more like SQL Server's T-SQL. PL/PGSQL has control structures, variables, and all of that fun stuff. PostgreSQL's SQL language implementation is much more strict about what functionality is available - it's a great implementation of SQL, but it's a querying language, not a procedural programming language.

Comment: what if table `person` has a identity field called `fid` so that i want to return `fid` i use `INSERT INTO person (firstName) VALUES (fname) RETURNING fid;` ?

Comment: How can you return the default results of the insert (e.g., X records inserted)?

Comment: it will be good if the user knows if the function was success or fail so return something that makes sense

Answer (score 8):

SQL-language functions' parameters are numbered, `$1`, `$2`, and so on. See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/xfunc-sql.html) for details. You could use [pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql.html) if you want named parameters and more advanced capabilities.